# Can an object expression refer to itself?

Tags: f#

I'm exploring converting our C# codebase to F#. This codebase uses an external library that provides an interface; one of the methods allows the library to create new instances of our class:

```cs
public class Worker : IWorker
{
    public IWorker CreateNewInstance()
    {
        return new Worker();
    }
}
```

Given the number of these classes, I'd like to take advantage of object expressions. Is there a way an object expression can refer to itself in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I would recommend this without knowing more about your use case, but something like this should work:

```ml
let rec makeWorker () =
    {
        new IWorker with
            member _.CreateNewInstance() = makeWorker ()
    }

let worker1 = makeWorker ()
let worker2 = worker1.CreateNewInstance()
```

Comment: This will work perfectly; thank you! Note that, for some reason, [I had to change](https://try.fsharp.org/#?code=C4TwDgpgBAkg6gewE4GsJKgXgLACgoFQCGARgM7BJEDGwUAthPSelAMJIRHAQByEAdxgA7CkWHVoALigBXYQEs6AWgB8sRKnR48AGwh1O1BkTSa0GABQBKLHkJQA3vYeFhgjcgtQBSgBYurq6MzKzAfgpkAHQcXDz8QqLA4pI2WCZmXqw2gVAAvjq4+nQCWUgAjOn0phDm2dZ6Bj5lAEzppVoVMZzcfIIiYhIQNkA&html=DwCwLgtgNgfAsAKAAQqaApgQwCb2ag4CdMTJcMABwFp0BHAVwEsA3AXgCIBhAewDsw6AdQAqAT0roOSAMb9BAzoIAeYAPThoAbhkhMAJwDOJNgzAAzagA4OeQhqy5EhAEY9sYu6mBq3HvD6asEA&css=Q) the `_.` to `this.`

Comment: That web site uses a (very) old version of F#. Modern versions should allow the single underscore, but either way is fine.